# check all checkbox and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a table list and each row has checkbox. 
And I trying to make if the checkbox is checked, add class on parent TR element.

But the problem is when check-all is checked, adding class on TR is not working.

This is what I tried here

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/upXr8/24

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkAll").change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        this.checked=true;
      })              
    }else{
      $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        this.checked=false;
      })              
    }
  });

  $(".checkbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
      var isAllChecked = 0;
      $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        if(!this.checked)
           isAllChecked = 1;
      })              
      if(isAllChecked == 0){ $("#checkAll").prop("checked", true); }     
    }else {
      $("#checkAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });



  $(".tbl tbody").on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
  });
  $('.tbl input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').addClass('selected');

});
```

```css
thead  tr { background:#aaa}
.wid1 { width:50px; }
.selected { background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl" border=1 width=100%>
<colgroup>
  <col class="wid1">
</colgroup>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkAll">all</td>
    <td>head</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="checkbox" checked></td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

How do I fix the code? 
Also How do I fix the jquery more simpler ? 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `$(this).parent().parent().addClass('selected')` in your loop when 'all' is checked, and `$(this).parent().parent().removeClass('selected')` when it's unchecked, as so:

```
$("#checkAll").change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        this.checked=true;
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('selected')
      })              
    }else{
      $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        this.checked=false;
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('selected')
      })              
    }
  });
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xodtyj34/) for updated fiddle

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpfull for you

```js
$(document).ready(
function() {
    //clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
    $("#checkAll").click(
        function() {
            $(this).closest('table').find('.checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
        }
    );
    //clicking the last unchecked or checked checkbox should check or uncheck the parent checkbox
    $('.checkbox').click(
        function() {
if ($(this).closest('table').find('#checkAll').prop('checked') && this.checked == false){
  $(this).closest('table').find('#checkAll').attr('checked', false);
}
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
    
                var flag = true;
                $(this).closest('table').find('.checkbox').each(
                    function() {
                        if (this.checked == false){
                        flag = false;
                        return;
                        }
                            
                    }
                );
                $(this).closest('table').find('#checkAll').prop('checked', flag);
                 $(this).closest('table').find('.checkbox').toggleClass('selected', flag);
            
        }
    );
}
);
```

```css
thead  tr { background:#aaa}
.wid1 { width:50px; }
.selected { background: red;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tbl" border=1 width=100%>
<colgroup>
  <col class="wid1">
</colgroup>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkAll">all</td>
    <td>head</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="checkbox" checked></td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```